Webpack 5 cause [ERR_WORKER_OUT_OF_MEMORY] while build on sever
Met a problem, that I try solve for 3 days already. When I try to build my project (Node.JS(21), Vue3, Quasar) with Webpack 5 on local machine (32 GB of RAM) and it builds without problem (uses 12Gb of RAM) But whene I try to build it on server working under docker. There are 216 GB of RAM. But in some moment I got the error
[ERR_WORKER_OUT_OF_MEMORY]: Worker terminated due to reaching memory limit: JS heap out of memory

Error [ERR_WORKER_OUT_OF_MEMORY]: Worker terminated due to reaching memory limit: JS heap out of memory
    at [kOnExit] (node:internal/worker:313:26)
    at Worker..onexit (node:internal/worker:229:20)
Emitted 'error' event on Worker instance at:
    at [kOnExit] (node:internal/worker:313:12)
    at Worker..onexit (node:internal/worker:229:20) {
  code: 'ERR_WORKER_OUT_OF_MEMORY'
}

Old version of project (with Node.JS(16), Vue2, no Quasar) build under Webpack 4 without problems.
webpack.config.js:
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const fs = require('fs');
const basicPath = 'resources/js/pages/';
const distPath = path.join(__dirname, '/public');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
const webpack = require('webpack')

const releaseVersion = () => {
    const releaseFile = 'version.json'
    const jsonFile = fs.readFileSync(releaseFile, 'utf8');
    const json = JSON.parse(jsonFile )
    const hash = json.hash
    
    return hash
}

const getFileName = (files) => {
    let obj = {}
    files.forEach(async (el) => {
        let fileName = el.split(basicPath)
        obj[fileName[1]] =  el
    })
    return obj
}

const entries = () => {

    const jsFiles =  glob.sync('./resources/js/pages/*.js*')
    const langFiles =  glob.sync('./resources/js/pages/lang/*.js*')
    const sharedFiles =  glob.sync('./resources/js/pages/shared/*.js*')

    const js = getFileName(jsFiles)
    const lang = getFileName(langFiles)
    const shared = getFileName(sharedFiles)

    const entries = Object.assign(
        js,
        lang,
        shared
    );
    
    return entries
}

const config  =  {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    mode: '',
    entry: entries,
    cache:  false,
    output: {
        filename: '[name]',
        chunkFilename: `[id].js?v${releaseVersion()}`,
        path: distPath + '/js',
        publicPath: "/CRM/js/"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|lang)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader",
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['npm_package_version']),
    ],

    resolve: {
        modules: ["node_modules"],
        alias: {
            'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js'
        },
        extensions: ['.vue', '.js']
    },

    performance: {
        hints: false
    }
}

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    if (argv.mode === 'production') {
        config.mode = 'production';
        config.devtool = false
    } else {
        config.mode = 'development';
        config.devtool = false
    }
    return config;
};

I tried using --max-old-space-size=16384, but there was no any result
I can't downgrade to Webpack 4 because Vue3 are not compatible with this version of webpack
